# handlebars show html tags instead of treat it as html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, handlebars.js

i've got handlebars template which i fill by some complex message (with html stuff like images, bold texts etc...). I don't know how to force this library to treat my message text as valid html-nodes with some text stuff.

I'm doing something like this:

```
<div class="title">
    <strong>
        <a href="/Home/Post/{{this.MESSAGE_ID}}">{{this.MESSAGE_TITLE}}</a>
    </strong>
</div>
```

where {{this.MESSAGE_TITLE}} can be correct html content.

Comment: Okay, i found a solution. It just require to use {{{ }}} instead of {{ }} to treat text as html.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `&` after the `{{` or `{{{`

```
{{&this.MESSAGE_TITLE}}
```

or

```
{{{this.MESSAGE_TITLE}}}
```

From the [mustache website](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) where handlebars is derived from...

> All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.
>
> You can also use & to unescape a variable: {{& name}}. This may be useful when changing delimiters